# release-please-action - reset version numbers

Tags: github-actions

How can I reset the version numbers which get published by release-please-action (https://github.com/google-github-actions/release-please-action)?
I tried having this in my action file, but with no luck:

```
jobs:
  release-please:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: google-github-actions/release-please-action@v2
        with:
          release-type: node
          package-name: release-please-action
          default-branch: dev
          handleGHRelease: true
          skip-github-release: true
          release-as: "0.0.1"
```

but this is the output of the action file:

```
Run google-github-actions/release-please-action@v2
  with:
    release-type: node
    package-name: release-please-action
    default-branch: dev
    handleGHRelease: true
    skip-github-release: true
    release-as: 0.0.1
    token: ***
    fork: false
    clean: true
    bump-minor-pre-major: false
    bump-patch-for-minor-pre-major: false
    monorepo-tags: false
    pull-request-title-pattern: chore${scope}: release${component} ${version}
(node:1565) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
⚠ No merged release PR found
✖ Unable to build candidate
✔ found 2 commits since a626739a3ca8
✔ release as patch: There are 0 BREAKING CHANGES and 0 features
✔ updating package-lock.json from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1
⚠ file npm-shrinkwrap.json did not exist
⚠ file samples/package.json did not exist
⚠ CHANGELOG.md not found
✔ creating CHANGELOG.md
✔ updating package.json from 0.0.1 to 1.4.1
✔ Starting GitHub PR workflow...
✔ Successfully found branch HEAD sha "f031f892aedc3f952f309a".
✔ Skipping branch creation step...
✔ Got the latest commit tree
✔ Successfully created a tree with the desired changes with SHA 93504b339a3b10d40
✔ Successfully created commit. See commit at https://api.github.com/repos/useraccount/FFYselfservingAPI/git/commits/04950bb981ffe48
✔ Successfully updated reference release-v1.4.1 to 0495ec509adc1212a8e5ab34831fb0bb981ffe48
✔ Found existing pull request for reference useraccount:release-v1.4.1. Skipping creating a new pull request.
✔ Successfully opened pull request: 25.
✔ update pull-request #25: chore: release 1.4.1
✔ adding label autorelease: pending to https://github.com/useraccount/FFYselfservingAPI/pull/25
✔ find stale PRs with label "autorelease: pending"
```

it still just wants to add minor numbers to 1.4.0... but it is supposed to start at 0.0.1
Any idea here what I am doing wrong, or what I am supposed to do? the documentation does not say anything about this (or I am really blind...).

cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its possible with an empty push:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "chore: release 0.0.1" -m "Release-As: 0.0.1"
```

cheers!